# Why did the App Engine Java SDK jump from 1.43 to 1.50 all at once?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sdk, release-management

For the past year I've been watching the App Engine incrementally move one step ahead each month or two.

Then yesterday it jumped from 1.43 to 1.50.

Does this mean the latest release is more significant than other recent releases?

Comment: Not just the Java SDK - both SDKs.

Answer (score 6):

Yes I'd say they had chosen to increment the 4 to 5, based on it delivering significant new functionality e.g. Pull Queues, Backends and **especially** the inclusion of the Go programming language (which is all tracked under the same version number)

Although the version number hasn't jumped as much as their pricing... No doubt when that is brought in they will move to 2.0 (to also mark their move out of preview)

Answer (score 0):

It was a major release. Jumps like this are common for versioning major releases.